# "I have tried Russian cuisine, and I liked it.” Why do we use Past Simple?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

**I have tried Russian cuisine & I liked it.**

Why do we use Past Simple in the "I liked it" part, if

1) there's no indication of when it happened,

2) I liked it at the same time when i tried it, so if we use Present Perfect for "I have tried", then this tense should refer to "I liked" too.

But for no logical reason, I'm sure I should say "I liked it".

Could you please help me explain this usage to my student?

Comment: Well, you can't say that you've tried it if it hasn't happened in the past, unless you can see into the future... so the very fact that you're talking about an experience tells you that it was in the past... you're not using the present tense - "I'm trying Russian food and I like it" - so it must be in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point #1.  There's no reason you can't use the simple past with things that occurred at an indefinite point in the past.

Comment: Is it correct "Russian cuisine" and not "russian cuisine"?

Comment: Past simple without a time is very common due to English's lack of a right now sense. Present simple being a fact or habit leaves a big gap.

Answer (score 2):

Using the simple past

> I liked it.

without further context, means you liked it when you tried it and you probably *still* like it.  You could also use the present tense to express the same meaning

> I tried it and I *like* it.

If you would say (past perfect)

> I had liked it.

it would be understood that you once liked it but no longer like it.

Past perfect is used to place something in the *more distant* past than simple past. If you used past perfect, the listener will expect something else to have happened in the *more recent* simple past.

If you would say (present perfect)

> I have liked it.

it would be understood that you liked it under certain circumstances in the past, which may or may not be present at the current time, so you may or may not like it now.

Comment: Even I liked it slightly suggests it may not still be true.

Answer (score 0):

The following sentence is actually not perfectly idiomatic. It is  slightly off.

> I have tried Russian cuisine and I liked it.

If we are referring to a particular incident in the past, as you are indeed doing here ("and liked it"), we use the simple past. Idiomatic would be

> I tried Russian cuisine and liked it.

However, if someone asks you

> Have you **ever** tried Russian cuisine?

you could reply:

> Yes, I **have tried** Russian cuisine. <sup>full stop</sup> I liked it.

or

> Yes, I **have tried** Russian cuisine and I **like** it.

Comment: very good explanation.